# for loop with dynamic if statement in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have these two list `group_name` and `group_ids_list` im looping these two list and I want to do an if condition based on the group id of this list. I want to know if there is a way to do this `if groupId == 0:` dynamically because this current example wont scale very well if I keep adding more groups and so on.

```
group_name = ['a','a','b','c', 'a', 'd']
group_ids_list = [0,0,1,2,0,3]
for groupName, groupId in itertools.zip_longest(group_name, group_ids_list):
    if groupId == 0:
        print('found group 0 name is {}'.format(groupName))
    elif groupId == 1:
        print('found group 1 name is {}'.format(groupName))
    elif groupId == 2:
        print('found group 2 name is {}'.format(groupName))
```

Comment: Is `group_ids` really supposed to be the indexes or is it supposed to be the values found in `group_ids_list`?

Comment: I updated my code im actually looping two list and yes group id is associated to an id. if you see the group_name it coresponds to some value like a if in group 0 or b if in group 1 and so on.

Comment: it looks like you changed the question a lot since I answered so I deleted my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to just print the group id and name. You can use string formatting to achieve this.

```
group_names = ['a','a','b','c', 'a', 'd']
group_ids = [0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 3]
for group_name, group_id in zip(group_names, group_ids):
    print('found group {} with name {}'.format(group_id, group_name))
```